# How to draw derived probability density function?

Tags: python, probability-density

Could you suggest ways to draw/visualize pdf(probability density function) of a function of random variables in `python`?

For example: Knowing `fx(x)` and mapping `Y=X^2`, how to draw pdf of `Y`?

Any reference to extending it for a function of two random variables is very much helpful. Thanks

PS: I would like to know how to use python programming or a standard library if there exists one.

Comment: A graph is first drawn, and then it can be converted to a pdf or an image. You may want to reword the question based on the sequence of outputs you are looking for.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  First you need to *calculate* the pdf then you can plot it.  You can *roll-your-own* or use a third party library to do it for you.  It isn't clear whether you are asking; 1) how to do the math, 2) how to write the program, or 3) requesting 3rd party library recommendations.

Comment: @wwii: I would like to know one example way of plotting so that I can extend for an arbitrary example. Consider fx(x) to be Gaussian if it is ok for you. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just monte-carlo the result? Throw random x values (in a range) at it and then graph the results?

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = [ 0.83395091,  1.4407822 ,  0.94962845,  0.98214451,  0.82661396,
      1.07335617,  0.98560571,  0.93095824,  0.89577214,  1.2390338 ,
      1.14833065,  1.04408037,  0.74040758,  1.131576  ,  1.30469568,
      1.07686211,  0.8574602 ,  1.13152259,  0.82153652,  0.9562608 ]
```

Print lines of text with lengths proportional to the probabilities

```
Y = [int(60*n) for n in Y]
for i, n in enumerate(Y):
    print('{:>3}: {}'.format(i,'*' * n))
```

---

```
  0: **************************************************
  1: **************************************************************************************
  2: ********************************************************
  3: **********************************************************
  4: *************************************************
  5: ****************************************************************
  6: ***********************************************************
  7: *******************************************************
  8: *****************************************************
  9: **************************************************************************
 10: ********************************************************************
 11: **************************************************************
 12: ********************************************
 13: *******************************************************************
 14: ******************************************************************************
 15: ****************************************************************
 16: ***************************************************
 17: *******************************************************************
 18: *************************************************
 19: *********************************************************
>>>
```